# Tkinter will not allow me to place an entry on a canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

When I run this code on its own, it does nothing.  But when run with the second set, it produces a very strange error.  It is meant to create a window that asks for an entry and then places a confirm button, but the entry does not place and creates the error.  If I remove the entry, the error disappears, but I need the entry.

I have searched around stack overflow and could not find anything to fix my problem.

If you have a suggestion for me to improve the question, please put it in the comments!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/BT Build 2/GUI.py", line 140, in <module>
    getrounds()
  File "/Users/Me/PycharmProjects/BT Build 2/GUI.py", line 138, in getrounds
    roundgetter.create_window(200, 130, window=roundsget)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2809, in create_window
    return self._create('window', args, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2771, in _create
    return self.tk.getint(self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!entry"
```

```
import tkinter as tk
def getrounds():
    root = tk.Tk()
    roundgetter = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300)
    roundgetter.pack()
    roundsprompt = tk.Label(text="How many rounds would you like to play?")
    roundsget = tk.Entry()
    def confirmed():
        intvar = roundsget.get()
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Confirm', command=lambda: confirmed())
    roundgetter.create_window(200, 160, window=button1)
    roundgetter.create_window(200, 130, window=roundsget)
    roundgetter.create_window(200, 100, window=roundsprompt)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is the main code

```
import time
import random
import tkinter as tk
seed = random.randint(-2147483647, 2147483647)
random.seed(seed)

class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
class things:
    ownedbarrel = 10
    ownedrefining = 10
    ownedgas = 10
    # will be redefined later
    Finalscore = 10000
    rounds = 16
    barrelcost = 40
    refiningcost = 10
    account = 10000
    gasbid = 0
    refiningbid = 0
    barrelbid = 0
    
me = tk.Tk()
infoteller = tk.Canvas(me, width=430, height=50)
infoteller.pack()
creator = tk.Label(me, text="Welcome to the Belvedere Trading Oil trading simulation Alpha 1.5.4")
system = tk.Label(me, text="Copyright © 2020 Grant Hutchinson")
infoteller.create_window(215, 15, window=creator)
infoteller.create_window(215, 40, window=system)
me.update()
infoteller.destroy()
time.sleep(3)
def main():
    for x in range(0, things.rounds):
        # cost change calculations
        costchange = random.randint(-4, 4)
        refiningcostchange = random.randint(-1, 1)
        things.refiningcost = things.refiningcost + refiningcostchange
        things.barrelcost = things.barrelcost + costchange
        things.gascost = things.barrelcost + 10 + costchange * 1.1 + random.randint(-2, 2)
        # Stablize
        if things.barrelcost < 10:
            things.barrelcost = things.barrelcost + 3
        if things.barrelcost > 70:
            things.barrelcost = things.barrelcost - 3
        if things.barrelcost < 20:
            things.barrelcost = things.barrelcost + 1
        if things.barrelcost > 60:
            things.barrelcost = things.barrelcost - 1
        if things.refiningcost > 12:
            things.refiningcost = things.refiningcost - 1
        if things.refiningcost < 8:
            things.refiningcost = things.refiningcost + 1
        # total cost calculations
        things.barrelask = things.barrelcost * 1.01
        things.barrelbid = things.barrelcost * 0.99
        things.barrelask = round(things.barrelask, 2)
        things.barrelbid = round(things.barrelbid, 2)
        things.refiningask = things.refiningcost * 1.05
        things.refiningbid = things.refiningcost * 0.95
        things.refiningask = round(things.refiningask, 2)
        things.refiningbid = round(things.refiningbid, 2)
        things.gasask = things.gascost * 1.01
        things.gasbid = things.gascost * 0.99
        things.gasask = round(things.gasask, 2)
        things.gasbid = round(things.gasbid, 2)

        
        root = tk.Tk()

        tellcanv = tk.Canvas(root, width=800, height=500)
        tellcanv.pack()

        l1 = tk.Label(root, text="Oil ask")
        a1 = tk.Label(root, text=things.barrelask)
        l2 = tk.Label(root, text="Oil bid")
        a2 = tk.Label(root, text=things.barrelbid)
        l3 = tk.Label(root, text="Refining ask")
        a3 = tk.Label(root, text=things.refiningask)
        l4 = tk.Label(root, text="Refining bid")
        a4 = tk.Label(root, text=things.refiningbid)
        l5 = tk.Label(root, text="Gas ask")
        a5 = tk.Label(root, text=things.gasask)
        l6 = tk.Label(root, text="Gas bid")
        a6 = tk.Label(root, text=things.gasbid)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 20, window=l1)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 40, window=a1)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 60, window=l2)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 80, window=a2)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 100, window=l3)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 120, window=a3)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 140, window=l4)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 160, window=a4)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 180, window=l5)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 200, window=a5)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 220, window=l6)
        tellcanv.create_window(400, 240, window=a6)
        tellcanv.pack()
        root.update()
        # Oil system
        self = tk.Tk()
        oilcanvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=300)
        oilcanvas.pack()
        self.oilget = tk.Entry(self)
        def oilbuy():
            intvar = self.oilget.get()
            print(intvar)
        def oilsell():
            intvar = self.oilget.get()
            print(intvar)
        roundsprompt = tk.Label(self,text="How much oil would you like to trade?")
        buyselector = tk.Button(self, text='Buy', command=oilbuy())
        sellselector = tk.Button(self, text='Sell', command=oilsell())
        oilcanvas.create_window(200, 120, window=roundsprompt)
        oilcanvas.create_window(200, 150, window=self.oilget)
        oilcanvas.create_window(180, 180, window=buyselector)
        oilcanvas.create_window(220, 180, window=sellselector)
        root.mainloop()

# get rounds
def getrounds():
    root = tk.Tk()
    roundgetter = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=300)
    roundgetter.pack()
    roundsprompt = tk.Label(text="How many rounds would you like to play?")
    roundsget = tk.Entry()
    def confirmed():
        intvar = roundsget.get()
        things.rounds = int(intvar)
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Confirm', command=lambda: confirmed())
    roundgetter.create_window(200, 160, window=button1)
    roundgetter.create_window(200, 130, window=roundsget)
    roundgetter.create_window(200, 100, window=roundsprompt)
    root.mainloop()
getrounds()

main()
```

It should make a window asking you how many rounds to play, but it does not.

Comment: The problem is because you are creating more than one instance of `Tk()`.

Comment: OK, how should I fix that? Should I only use one somehow?

Comment: Grant: if you need to create additional windows, you can create a [`Toplevel`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-application-windows.htm) widget.

Comment: I figured out, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did in the code (I gave a look, but it's too complicated), if your problem is to create more windows take a look at this post I made about this: [how to make more windows with tkinter](https://pythonprogramming.altervista.org/more-windows-with-tkinter-new-version/)